# Navbar Expands to Cover Top of Screen When You Scroll Down the Page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I was looking at the new MemSQL website at http://www.memsql.com/product.  When you scroll past the navbar that loads in the middle of the page, it expands and sticks to the top of the screen.

The initial view:

[image]

After scrolling past the navbar:
[image]

How would you implement something like this?  Is there a simple way to do it through Bootstrap?

Comment: Need JS to determine when the viewport is passed the nav height, then set it to 'fixed'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into jQuery Waypoints plugin.  Specifically this.  http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/

There is a lot of stuff that Waypoints can do though.  Check it out!

Comment: In regards to wanting to change the nav size, etc, you can use Waypoints to add a class (or pretty much do whatever) to your nav when it gets to the top.

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#get-started